# Turn printscreen into ctrl printscreen

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, clipboard, gnome-screenshot, print-screen

I have Ubuntu 18.04, and when I press the <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> button on my laptop, the file gets saved to `~/Pictures`.

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd>, then the file gets saved to my clipboard.

I want to **default** somehow, such that whenever I print <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> alone, it still automatically copies it inside my clipboard.

Is this possible? I would like the screenshot to also be a part of my `~/Pictures`, but if I forget to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, I still want it to be copied.

How can this be done?

I have GNOME installed.

Answer (score 2):

Just a Workaround

1. Disable the Shortcut key for <kbd>Print</kbd>
2. make the Shortcut <kbd>Print</kbd> for 'Copy a screenshot to clipboard'
3. make the Shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd> for 'Save a screenshot to Pictures'

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to rebind the keyboard shortcut in `gnome-shell`:

Applications > System Tools > Settings > Keyboard > Search > 'Clipboard' > Copy a screenshot to clipboard > *PrtSc* > Replace:

[image]

To have it do both, you'd want to create a custom shortcut pointing to a script:

~/bin/doubleshot.sh:

```
$!/bin/bash
gnome-screenshot -c
gnome-screenshot -f $HOME/Pictures/Screenshot_$(date +$Y%m%d_%H%M%S).png
```